# Custom view to select a value

Tags: java, beginner, android, xml, layout

I created a Custom view to select a value. I use horizontal Recyclerview to select an integer value and 2 buttons that decrease or increase the values. Could you consider the code and tell how it can be improved?

SliderValueSelectorView

```
public class SliderValueSelectorView extends ConstraintLayout implements View.OnClickListener {

private TextView valueText;
private View selectValueView;
private RecyclerView valueRecyclerView;
private LinearSnapHelper valueSnapHelper = new LinearSnapHelper();
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager valueLayoutManager;
private ValueSelectAdapter valueAdapter;
private SnapRecyclerUtil recyclerUtil = new SnapRecyclerUtil();

private BigDecimal value = new BigDecimal(70);
private BigDecimal valueStep = new BigDecimal(0.1);

private int minValue = 1;
private int maxValue = 300;

private int scale = 1;
private RoundingMode roundingMode = RoundingMode.HALF_UP;

public SliderValueSelectorView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    initView();
}

public SliderValueSelectorView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    initView();
}

public SliderValueSelectorView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    initView();
}

private void initView() {
    View view = inflate(getContext(), R.layout.slider_selector_layout, this);
    initValue();
    initRecycler(view);
    valueText = view.findViewById(R.id.value);
    view.findViewById(R.id.increase).setOnTouchListener(new RepeatListener(200, this));
    view.findViewById(R.id.reduce).setOnTouchListener(new RepeatListener(200, this));
}

private void initValue() {
    value = value.setScale(scale, roundingMode);
    valueStep = valueStep.setScale(scale, roundingMode);
}

private void initRecycler(View view) {
    valueAdapter = new ValueSelectAdapter(maxValue + 1, minValue);
    valueRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.values);
    valueLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
    OffsetItemDecoration itemDecoration = new OffsetItemDecoration();
    valueRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(itemDecoration);
    recyclerUtil.installationRecyclerView(
            valueRecyclerView, valueSnapHelper, valueLayoutManager,
            valueAdapter, recyclerViewScrollListener, getRecyclerPosition());
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    int id = v.getId();
    if (id == R.id.increase) {
        stepWeight(valueStep);
    } else if (id == R.id.reduce) {
        stepWeight(valueStep.negate());
    }
}

private void stepWeight(BigDecimal stepFractional) {
    double result = getValueText() + stepFractional.doubleValue();
    if ((result > minValue + 1 || stepFractional.doubleValue() > 0) && (result <= maxValue || stepFractional.doubleValue() < 0)) {
        int startPosition = value.intValue();
        value = value.add(stepFractional);
        if (startPosition != value.intValue()) {
            scrollToCurrentValue();
        }
    }
    valueText.setText(this.toString());
}

private RecyclerView.OnScrollListener recyclerViewScrollListener = new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrolled(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
        super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
        selectValueView = recyclerUtil.getCenterView(valueSnapHelper, valueLayoutManager);
        showSelectValue();
    }
};

@SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
private void showSelectValue() {
    TextView selectView = selectValueView.findViewById(R.id.select_weight);
    int newWeight = Integer.parseInt(selectView.getText().toString());
    value = value.add(new BigDecimal(newWeight - value.intValue()));
    valueText.setText(this.toString());
}

@Override
@NonNull
public String toString() {
    return value.toString();
}

public void setString(String weightStr) {
    try {
        value = new BigDecimal(weightStr);
        scrollToCurrentValue();
    } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException(weightStr +
                " not a number, therefore it is impossible to convert " + weightStr + " to mass");
    }
}

public float getValueText() {
    return Float.parseFloat(this.toString());
}

private void scrollToCurrentValue() {
    recyclerUtil.toTargetPosition(valueLayoutManager, valueSnapHelper, valueRecyclerView, getRecyclerPosition());
}

public BigDecimal getValueStep() {
    return valueStep;
}

public void setValueStep(BigDecimal valueStep) {
    this.valueStep = valueStep.setScale(scale, roundingMode);
}

public int getMinValue() {
    return minValue;
}

public void setMinValue(int minValue) {
    this.minValue = minValue;
    this.valueAdapter.setMinValue(minValue);
    this.valueAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

private int getRecyclerPosition() {
    return value.intValue() - minValue;
}

public int getMaxValue() {
    return maxValue;
}

public void setMaxValue(int maxValue) {
    this.maxValue = maxValue;
    this.valueAdapter.setMaxValue(maxValue + 1);
    this.valueAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public BigDecimal getValue() {
    return value;
}

public void setValue(BigDecimal value) {
    this.value = value.setScale(scale, roundingMode);
    scrollToCurrentValue();
}

public int getScale() {
    return scale;
}

public void setScale(int scale) {
    this.scale = scale;
}

public RoundingMode getRoundingMode() {
    return roundingMode;
}

public void setRoundingMode(RoundingMode roundingMode) {
    this.roundingMode = roundingMode;
}
}
```

slider_selector_layout.xml

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/weightSelector"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/border"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/description">

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/reduce"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/image_icon"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/image_icon"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@null"
    android:rotation="180"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:src="@drawable/weight_change"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/value"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:textColor="@color/darkGreen"
    android:textSize="32sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/increase"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/reduce"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/increase"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/image_icon"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/image_icon"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@null"
    android:gravity="end"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:src="@drawable/weight_change"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/values"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/border"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/increase" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/top_indicator"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/image_icon"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/image_icon"
    android:rotation="180"
    android:src="@drawable/weight_indicator"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/values"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/values" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/bottom_indicator"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/image_icon"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/image_icon"
    android:src="@drawable/weight_indicator"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/values"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
```

RepeatListener

```
public class RepeatListener implements View.OnTouchListener {

    private Handler handler = new Handler();

    private final int initialInterval;
    private final View.OnClickListener clickListener;
    private View touchedView;

    private Runnable handlerRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (touchedView.isEnabled()) {
                handler.postDelayed(this, initialInterval);
                clickListener.onClick(touchedView);
            } else {
                handler.removeCallbacks(handlerRunnable);
                touchedView.setPressed(false);
                touchedView = null;
            }
        }
    };

    public RepeatListener(int initialInterval, View.OnClickListener clickListener) {
        if (clickListener == null)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("null runnable");
        if (initialInterval < 0)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("negative interval");

        this.initialInterval = initialInterval;
        this.clickListener = clickListener;
    }

    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        switch (motionEvent.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                handler.removeCallbacks(handlerRunnable);
                handler.postDelayed(handlerRunnable, initialInterval);
                touchedView = view;
                touchedView.setPressed(true);
                clickListener.onClick(view);
                return true;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                handler.removeCallbacks(handlerRunnable);
                touchedView.setPressed(false);
                touchedView = null;
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```